# Value of parts on a totaled car [MO, US]

Tags: united-states, civil-law, insurance, motor-vehicle, missouri

Suppose I was driving a totaled car and hit by someone, damaging one side mirror. The mirror was in good condition before this accident, although the car was totaled.

Can I file a claim against his insurance company to fix the mirror (assuming him at fault)? Does the mirror itself still have financial value, legally?

Comment: Why would he not have to pay for the mirror?

Comment: @Putvi He would argue that the car worth nothing, so there's no financial loss?

Comment: A totaled car should be written off and is almost guaranteed to not be legally driveable, that it's even physically driveable at all is a surprise. You wouldn't be covered by any insurance, and it's likely that they have a claim against you.

Comment: @Nij If the damage to a car would cost more to repair than the market value of the car it will be declared "totaled". This may well not mean it is undrivable. It may later be sold and refurbished and registered and insured, as a damaged used car. A totaled car normally becomes the property of the insurer, and has a value, whether derivable or not.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Many insurance companies offer the option that owner pay them the salvage value but keep possession of the car. And I should be able to drive it as long as it is safe. I don't understand the downvotes.

Comment: @Nij why would the insurer have a claim against the owner?

Comment: [The other driver] likely has a claim against you. @Ryan

Comment: "Totaled" is not a declarative statement by any authority, just a descriptive one about the extent of damage viz. the vehicle is *totally* damaged. Being written off is the declarative statement that the repairs are uneconomical, and has to be accompanied by deregistering the vehicle, making it illegal to drive, regardless of whether it's physically functional.

Comment: @Nij Neither of those are proper terms. A vehicle where repairs are feasible but exceed value is a _constructive total loss_. A vehicle where repairs are clearly infeasible is an _actual total loss_. A vehicle which was a total loss but repaired is a vehicle with a _rebuilt title_, which is what I think the OP is talking about.

Comment: @Nij A constructive total loss can arise due to non-safety issues, such as paint damage/vandalism on a old low-value car. An actual total loss can arise when a vehicle is missing, e.g. it was stolen. If a vehicle is stolen and not recovered after a certain time, typically 30 days, insurance will pay for its value. If it is recovered after that time, it will be branded with a rebuilt title, even if the vehicle is completely undamaged.

Answer (score 1):

### The at fault driver is liable for the damage

To avoid the complication that a written-off vehicle normally is not drivable and becomes the property of the insurer, let’s assume that it is legally parked in on the owner’s premises and an at fault driver strikes and destroys the mirror (or any other part) - they are liable for the damage done. The scrap value of the mirror.